# Dotnet Core 3.1 endpoint routing for api with areas

Tags: api, .net-core, routes

At this time, all of my controllers have a decorator at the top of the class like this:

```
[Route("[area]/api/[controller]")]
```

I feel like this could be done in the `Startup.cs` file using an endpoint routing command, but for the life of me, I can't figure out the syntax.

Does anyone know how I would enter this into `Configure -> app.UseEndpoints`

(I know how I would do it in ASP.net)

Comment: This may or may not be helpful, but by Microsoft's own determination what you have currently is typically how to implement the routing for an API. "It's typical to use conventional routes for controllers serving HTML pages for browsers, and attribute routing for controllers serving REST APIs." To add a bit of reassurance that's how all of our azure dotnet api's routes are handled.